# Python Plotly sign in error

Tags: python, plotly

I get an error message while using plotly for charts. My code reads as below:

```
import plotly as py
py.tools.set_credentials_file(username='myaccount', api_key='myapikey')

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as plotly_tools
from plotly.graph_objs import *

py.sign_in("myaccount", "mypassword")

(Some code that is not related to this problem.)

py.iplot(data, filename='apple stock moving average')
```

The error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       py.iplot(data, filename='apple stock moving average')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line
>   151, in iplot
>       url = plot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line
>   241, in plot
>       res = _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line
>   1404, in _send_to_plotly
>       raise exceptions.PlotlyError(r['error'])
>
> PlotlyError: Aw, snap! You tried to use our API as the user
>   'myaccount', but the supplied API key doesn't match our records. You
>   can view your API key at plot.ly/settings.
>
> You're most likely getting this message because your local credentials
>   file isn't synced with the Plotly server you're communicating with.
>
> Go to plot.ly//getting-started (e.g.,
>   plot.ly/python/getting-started) for more information.
>
> Make sure that you're logged in as myaccount.
>
> Need help? Please try searching Plotly's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly'>Stack Overflow channel.

I think plotly is not properly setup on my local machine, but could not figure out the correct way to solve this. I am using spyder from Anaconda3 and is under windows7.

Anyone could help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using myapikey at the top, and mypassword when you sign in. Use the same variable in both places.